# compare value with list of int in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-awx

Want to compare values with list for int and display msg values greater than 15

```yaml
  tasks:

    - name: Create a List variable and print it
      set_fact:
        Continents: ["10","20"]
    - name: set fatc
      set_fact:
         int_list: "{{ Continents|map('int')|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{greater than 15}}"
      when: "{{int_list}}" > 15
```

Getting error as below:

```
The offending line appears to be:

        msg: "{{ list }}"
      when: "{{int_list}}" > 15
                             ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}
Should be written as:
    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Expected Output:

```
greater than 15
```

Comment: When condition should not be in  brackets. Leave it as int_list only and not "{{int_list}}"

Comment: "{{greater than 15}}" should not be a variable. If your goal is to print the string "greater than 15" leave it without the curly brackets.

Comment: I have added my answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same with two tasks. Change your list to integers. Make the debug task to loop through the Continents variable.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Create a variable with a list of integers
      set_fact:
        Continents: [10, 20]

    - debug:
        msg: "greater than 15"
      loop: "{{ Continents }}"
      when: item > 15  ##item becomes each value of the Continents variable. So, 10, 20 and so on.
```

Gives:

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item=10)
ok: [localhost] => (item=20) => {
     "msg": "greater than 15"
}
```

Comment: its really helpful for me

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to show only those integers in the list that are greater than 15, you can use the [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select) filter:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - name: Create a list of integers
      set_fact:
        int_list: [10, 20]

    - name: Find integers greater than 15
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ int_list | select('>', 15) }}"
```

The output of this playbook is:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Create a list of integers] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Find integers greater than 15] *******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=20) => {
    "msg": 20
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: getting below error:
 15] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7f4d361a1cd0>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}

Comment: same code run, but getting above error.

Comment: It looks like you're running an older version of Ansible. Consider upgrading, or modify the `loop` argument to look like: `"{{ int_list | select('>', 15) | list }}"`